# SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis strange behavior

Tags: c#, iis, smtp

I think i need some guru lights!

```
public void SendEndingMail(string fileName)
        {
            SmtpClient client;
            client = new SmtpClient("smtp.myserver.com", 25);
            //client = new SmtpClient();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(""))
            {
                System.Net.NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("", "");
                client.Credentials = credential;
            }
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            //client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;

            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("mailing@mydom.com", "Elec");
            MailAddress toAdrress = new MailAddress("mailing@mydom.com");

            using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(fromAddress, toAdrress))
            {

                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(fileName));
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
                mailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                try
                {
                    client.Send(mailMessage);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Is that true that:
when i set 
     client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
It does not matter whichever smtp server i use

```
        client = new SmtpClient("smtp.myserver.com", 25);
        //client = new SmtpClient();
```

The both lines are the same since it will use LOCAL IIS ?!!!

Is this is true, it is not normal that the API is build this way!? it is very confusing...

Thanks
Jonathan

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, when the SmtpClient sends the email, it looks at the .DeliveryMethod value. If the value is Network, then it sends via network. If it is PickupDirectoryFromIis, then it ignores any specified SMTP server (because it just writes and the email to the filesystem), and writes it to the Pickup directory. No network communication takes place.

Comment: Thanks Dave but i do not understand the last sentence "and writes it to the Pickup directory. No network communication takes place." where is the magic? it must be sent through an smtp server ?

Comment: Hi,
The SmtpClient will write the email directly too the pickup directory. Once it is written, the IIS SMTP service will come by, analyze the mail, if it accepted, it gets moved to the Queue directory. From there, the message is sent on, either to a smart host, or to the recipient's mail server.

Cheers!
Dave

Comment: When I say "From there", I mean the IIS SMTP service will then attempt to delilver the message. If the message can't be delivered, it stays in the Queue for possible delivery retries. Or, if delivery fails entirely, it gets moved to the Badmail directory. --Dave

Comment: So why microsoft allows to put a smtp server in the creation of the smtpclient if not used when user sets the pickup option....

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug in the Send routine - it creates an smtp server object even if one isn't specified, and when it later (after Send) tries to dispose it, it throws an exception. This happens AFTER the mail is successfully placed in the pickup directory, so the mail will be sent.

Workarounds:

1. Specify localhost as SMTP server. It won't be used, but prevents the exception.
2. A blind try/catch around the Send method (BAD solution).