# Code Conversion from Classic ASP to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp-classic, smtp

My client have a classic ASP site on his dedicated server on which he sends mail using IIS (Its working properly there).

```
Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
Mail.Host = "localhost" ' Specify a valid SMTP server
Mail.Username = "mail@site.com"
Mail.Password = "password"
Mail.From = "info@site.com"
```

I tried converting this to ASP.NET like this.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "localhost";
smtp.Port = 25;
//smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mail@site.com", "password");

smtp.Send(message);
```

But this doesn't work. Its almost legacy app without any error logger / monitoring and I cannot debug the code on online server.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: what exactly is wrong? are you expecting the email to go to an smtp server? if so, your delivery method is probably your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243033/smtpdeliverymethod-pickupdirectoryfromiis-strange-behavior

Comment: iis is configured for smtp mail here

Comment: does the email show up in the queue folder? i believe the path is: c:\inetpub\mailroot\Queue

Comment: Are you able to telnet to localhost port 25 on that machine (`telnet localhost 25` from cmd)? Does it answer? Does the message get written to the correct IIS drop location, or does the file not even get created?

Comment: "It doesn't work" - what exactly happens?

Comment: @Zach: I will definitely ask my client to check that.

Comment: @Jaymz: I will get IP and telnet that. But I dont think port 25 is closed.

Comment: @Kieren: I dont know.I dont get a mail. Thats why I said " Its almost legacy app without any error logger / monitoring and I cannot debug the code on online server"

Comment: If you intend to send through an SMTP, don't set DeliveryMethod to PickupDirectoryFromIis. You're SmtpClient setup is conflicting.

Comment: @thomask: then what should the method be?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a permissions issue. Check this [thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1032876.aspx?PageIndex=1) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check to see if port 25 is being blocked, as shown in http://kb.siteground.com/article/How_to_check_whether_SMTP_port_25_is_blocked.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the pickup directory is being monitored by your local SMTP server if you use this method:

smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;

If it is not then the messages will remain there without being sent.